# JQuery - validator plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I want to use the validator plugin together with Twitter Bootstrap. However, it does not really work at the moment and I do not now why.

My form:

```
<div class="form_errors"></div>
<div class="form_holder_invitee" id="form_holder_invitee">
    <form class="homepage_invitee_form" id="homepage_invitee_form" action="add"
    method="get">
        <input name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email_address_new"
        type="text placeholder">
        <br>
        <input name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" id="firstname_new" type="text placeholder">
        <input name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastname_new" type="text placeholder">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary opal_btn" id="submit_form_new"
        value="submit">Request Invitation</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my validatorScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form_holder_invitee').validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            lastName: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form_errors')
                .removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function (element) {
            element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                .closest('.form_errors')
                .removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
    });

}); // end document.ready
```

And a little bit of CSS to show the error:

```css
label.error {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

However, when I type into the form, nothing happens. The libraries are properly configured in my html. Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest looking into using [Parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/) vs the validator plugin. It eliminates the need to have to declare rules in javascript. It looks at your dom attributes to handle validation rules and error messages.

Comment: In the original version of your question, you were improperly targeting the `div`.  Now it shows that you are targeting the `form`.  Please don't edit your question in such a way that the accepted answer becomes meaningless.  I edited so the accepted answer has relevance again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it's because you've registered the .validate function on your wrapper div instead of your form? but i don't know the validator plugin.